# Equivalent definitions of compactly supported in the case of induced representation

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group of totally disconnected (td) type, meaning every neighborhood of $1_G$ contains a compact open subgroup.  Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$.  Then $H$ is also of td type.

Let $(\sigma,W)$ be a smooth representation of $H$.  So $W$ is a complex vector space, $\sigma: H \rightarrow \textrm{GL}(W)$ is an abstract representation of $H$, and the stabilizer in $H$ of any vector is an open subgroup.  Equivalently, every vector is stabilized by an open compact subgroup of $H$.

Let $\textrm{Ind}_H^G(\sigma)$ be the complex vector space of functions $f: G \rightarrow W$ with the following properties:

1 .  There is an open compact subgroup $K$ of $G$ (depending on $f$) such that $f$ is right $K$-invariant ($f(gk) = f(g)$ for all $g \in G, k \in K$).

2 .  For all $h \in H$ and $g \in G$, $f(hg) = \sigma(h)f(g)$.

Let $\textrm{c-Ind}_H^G(\sigma)$ be the subrepresentation of $\textrm{Ind}_H^G(\sigma)$ of functions $f$ satisfying the addition property:

3 .  $f$ is compactly supported modulo $H$.  This means that there is a compact set $Z$ (depending on $f$) such that $\{ x \in G : f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is contained in the product set $H.Z$.  Equivalently, we can take closures and say that the support of $f$ is contained in $H.Z$.  This is because $H.Z$ is closed, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71983/product-of-compact-and-closed-in-topological-group-is-closed).

I have seen people interchange this definition with saying that the image of the support of $f$ is $H \backslash G$ is compact.  But looking at the comments of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348461/support-compact-modulo-subgroup) question, I am a bit confused on what is and isn't true.  Compactly supported modulo a subgroup doesn't appear to always coincide with having the image in the coset space compact.  Can someone clarify what, if anything, the condition (3) is equivalent to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact open subgroup of $G$, and $f \in \textrm{Ind}_H^G(\sigma)$.  Let $S$ be the support of $f$.  Then $S$ is stabilized by $H$ on the left, and stabilized on the right by $K$.  Hence $S$ is a union of double cosets $HgK$.  The following are equivalent:

(i): $f$ vanishes off a set of the form $H.Z$ for $Z \subseteq G$ compact.

(ii): $S$ is contained in a set of the form $H.Z$ for $Z$ compact.

(iii): $S = H.Z$ for a compact set $Z \subseteq G$.

(iv): The image of $S$ in $H \setminus G$ is compact.

(v): $S$ is a finite union of double cosets $HgK$.

Proof: Since the nonvanishing set of $f$ is right $K$-stable (resp. left $H$-stable), so is its closure $S$, which is the support of $f$.  Hence $S$ is a union of right cosets $xK$, and in particular $S$ is both open and closed. Moreover $S$ is a union of left cosets $Hx$, and being left $H$ and right $K$-stable is a union of double cosets.

(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) is clear, and (i) $\Rightarrow $ (ii) is obtained by taking closures, and using the fact that $H.Z$ is closed (since $H$ is closed and $Z$ is compact).

For (iv) $\Rightarrow$ (iii), suppose the image of $\pi(S)$ in $H \backslash G$ is compact.  There is a compact set $Z$ of $G$ such that $\pi(Z) = \pi(S)$ e.g. Lemma 5.2 of these [notes][2].  Since $S$ is left $H$-stable, the preimage of $\pi(S)$ is $S$.  And the preimage of $\pi(Z)$ is $H.Z$.

For (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv), the image of $S$ in $H \backslash G$ is closed, since $S = \pi^{-1}\pi(S)$ is a saturated closed set.  Being a closed subset of the compact set $\pi(H.Z) = \pi(Z)$, it must be compact.

(v) $\Rightarrow$ (iv): We have $S = Hg_1K \cup \cdots Hg_tK = H(g_1K \cup \cdots g_tK)$ with $g_1K \cup \cdots g_tK$ compact.

(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (v): $S$ is a union of various right cosets $xK$.  The image of these cosets are open in $H \backslash G$, so the image of $S$ is a union of finitely many images $\pi(xK)$, say $\pi(S) = \pi(x_1K) \cup \cdots \cup \pi(x_tK)$.  Taking preimages, we get

$$S = \pi^{-1}\pi(S) = \pi^{-1}\pi(x_1K) \cup \cdots \cup \pi^{-1}\pi(x_tK)$$

with $\pi^{-1} \pi(xK) = HxK$.

Comment: I believe this is true.  I have provided a proof of this result as a second answer, where you may take $\Omega  = \pi(S)$.

Comment: ^The person above me deleted their comment because they were probably embarrassed, but they claimed that $Z \mapsto \pi(Z)$ is not necessarily a surjection from compact subsets of $G$ to compact sets of $G/H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**: Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$.  Let $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ be the canonical projection. If $\Omega \subset G/H$ is compact, then there exists a compact set $Z \subset G$ such that $\pi(Z) = \Omega$.

Proof: if we let $E = \pi^{-1}(\Omega)$, then $E$ is closed, but not necessarily compact.  Since $G$ is locally compact, we may cover $E$ by open sets $U_i$ whose closures are compact.  Since $\pi$ is an open mapping, and $\Omega$ is compact, we can write $\Omega \subseteq \pi(U_1) \cup \cdots \cup \pi(U_n)$ for a finite set of indices $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Now let $Z = \Big( \overline{U_1} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{U_t} \Big) \cap E$.  This is a compact set in $G$, and we claim

$$\pi(Z) = \Omega.$$

It is clear that $\pi(Z) \subseteq \Omega$.  Conversely, supposing $x \in \Omega$, we know that there exists $1 \leq i \leq n$ and a $g \in U_i$ such that $x = \pi(g)$.  Clearly $g \in E$ and therefore $g \in Z$.  Thus every $x \in \Omega$ is equal to $\pi(g)$ for some $g \in Z$, which means that $\Omega \subseteq \pi(Z)$.